# Where to find Ultimate Survivor Bundle items and outfits in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

I just redeem the `Ultimate Survivor Bundle` DLC and can't find the outfits in my "backpack" at `Safe Zones`, nor the items in my inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not released yet, and will soon. It should automatically come into your game once released and redeemed.

[Read more at Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/dying-light-will-get-its-long-awaited-hard-mode-on-ma-1689395474)

[image: Bundle]

Comment: Strange, i can already redeem and download it. We well see in a few days

Comment: I get the blueprints and the outfits to my backpack with the March 10 update.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered once you defeate the game go to the main menu it should say that you now have outfits available.

Answer (score -2):

G'day I've just bought the costumes for dying light bundle pack nd nothing has come through can anyone give me an answer? Why thanx

Comment: Welcome to Arquade. Please don't post questions as answers. If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button on the top right of the page.